# Reducer doesn't catch when action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I want to make api call in my small react/redux app. I am still learning redux, so obviously I am no perfect at it. 
My problem is: reducer doesn't get data from action, when i'm calling api. 
when i log in console action payload, it gets correct data from server. and everting seems ok, but reducer just doesn't realize that action has occurred. Here is my code:

actions/apicall.js

```
import Api from '../api/Api';
import * as types from './actionsTypes';

export function loadSuccess(payload){
console.log(payload)
return {type: types.DATA_LOADED, payload}
};

export function loadData() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return Api.getAllBeers().then(payload => {
      loadSuccess(payload);
      console.log(payload);
   }).catch(error => {
     throw(error);
   });
  };
}
```

reducers/data_reducer

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionsTypes';

export default function beerReducer(state = initialState, action) {
console.log(state);
console.log(action.payload);
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.DATA_LOADED:
      return action.payload
    case types.SELECTED_BEER:
      return action.payload
    default:
     return state;
 }
}
```

reducers/index

```
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import beerReducer from './data_reducer';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    beerReducer,
});

export default (allReducers);
```

api/Api

```
class Api {
  static getAllBeers() {
      const request = new Request(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers`, {
  method: 'GET'
});
    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
}
export default Api;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './resources/css/main.css';
import App from './resources/App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import {loadData} from './resources/actions/apicall';

const store = configureStore();

store.dispatch(loadData());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

do You have any idea what is wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have to dispatch the action in your `apicall.js`:
`dispatch(loadSuccess(payload));`